# fibonacci and prime numbers in one series

Tags: java, algorithm, primes, fibonacci

I am trying to do some mock questions of coding for an entrance exam, I came about this question and I am stuck at the PRIME NUMBERS part.

Here is the question:

Consider the below series: 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 7, 5, 11, 8, 13, 13, 17, … This series is a mixture of 2 series – all the odd terms in this series form a Fibonacci series and all the even terms are the prime numbers in ascending order. Write a program to find the Nth term in this series. For example, when N = 14, the 14th term in the series is 17. So only the value 17 should be printed out.

```
public class OandF {
    // main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(dofibo(9));

    }

    public static int dofibo(int m) {


        if(m == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if(m == 1) {
            return 1;
        }

        return dofibo(m-1) + dofibo(m-2);

    }


}
// as you can see this is where I got to, and I don't know how to proceed
```

Comment: Prime numbers are increasingly expensive to calculate. since you want a continuing series, you need to either calculate them in growing bulks using Sieve of Eratosthenes, or go through with try and error, until you find one. But the runtime will plummet either way.

Comment: Goal: A number will be entered by the user which will be the position of the given series above, and to print out the number at that position of the series

Comment: means that series are stored in somewhere like array or anywhere ?

Comment: This is the exact question: Consider the below series:

1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 7, 5, 11, 8, 13, 13, 17, …

This series is a mixture of 2 series – all the odd terms in this series form a Fibonacci series and all the even terms are the prime numbers in ascending order. 

Write a program to find the Nth term in this series. For example, when N = 14, the 14th term in the series is 17. So only the value 17 should be printed out.

Comment: If N is odd, calculate then (N/2)th Fibonacci number, else, calculate the (N/2)th prime number.

Comment: You can use a sieve here, to generate the primes. You should also cache the primes you already found.

Comment: A month ago, this [same problem in Python was migrated to CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/222178/166993)  My solution then was to [interlace a pair of independent generators](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/222341/166993)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to find the nth Prime number, the easiest way is to keep counting the prime numbers from 1 to n. But this is very time consuming otherwise refer to Fermat's theorems or Sieve of Eratosthenes.

```
private boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n == 2 || n == 3) return true;
    for(int i = 2; i < (int)Math.sqrt(n) + 1; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public int nthPrime(int n) {
    int number, primeCount;
    for(number = 2, primeCount = 0; primeCount < n; number++) {
        if (isPrime(number)) {
            ++primeCount;
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it may solve your problem.

```
class FibonacciExample1 {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  int input = 20;
  fibonacci(input);
  System.out.print("-----------------------------");
  prime(input);
 }
 public static void fibonacci(int input) {
  int n1 = 0, n2 = 1, n3, i, count = input;
  System.out.print(n1 + " " + n2);

  for (i = 2; i < count; ++i) {
   n3 = n1 + n2;
   System.out.print(" " + n3);
   n1 = n2;
   n2 = n3;
  }
 }

 public static void prime(int input) {
  int i = 0;
  int num = 0;
  String primeNumbers = "";

  for (i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
   int counter = 0;
   for (num = i; num >= 1; num--) {
    if (i % num == 0) {
     counter = counter + 1;
    }
   }
   if (counter == 2) {
    primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i + " ";
   }
  }
  System.out.println(primeNumbers);
 }
}
```

Comment: This appears to completely ignore the OP's problem.  This doesn't interlace the two sequences, but simply does one then the other.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make these two programs into simpler, infinite generators that are easier to debug and then sequence:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Fibonacci {

    int a = 0, b = 1;

    int next() {
        int c = a;

        a = b;
        b += c;

        return a;
    }
}

class Prime {

    ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

    int number = 2;

    int next() {

        if (number == 2) { // special case
            primes.add(number);
            number = 1;
            return 2;
        }

        outer: while (true) {
            number += 2;

            for (int divisor: primes) {

                if (divisor * divisor > number) {
                    break outer;
                }

                if (number % divisor == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        primes.add(number);
        return number;
    }
}

public class Example {

    public static int sequence(int n) {
        int nth = -1;

        if ((n % 2) == 0) {
            Fibonacci fibonacci_generator = new Fibonacci();

            for (int i = 0; i < (n / 2) + 1; i++) {
                nth = fibonacci_generator.next();
            }
        } else {
            Prime prime_generator = new Prime();

            for (int i = 0; i < (n + 1) / 2; i++) {
                nth = prime_generator.next();
            }
        }

        return nth;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(sequence(13));  // 14th element counting from zero
    }
}
```